# Dynamically add and position form items based on list in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, dynamically-generated

So I'm trying to show a list of activities on my form.

The activity class looks like:

```
 class Activity
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int IncidentID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int TimeSpent { get; set; }
        public Activity(int iD, int incidentID, string description, int timeSpent)
        {
            this.ID = iD;
            this.IncidentID = incidentID;
            this.Description = description;
            this.TimeSpent = timeSpent;
        }

    }
```

My end goal is to have something like this mock up:

[image]

A number of activities, however, is chosen at runtime and can change (since it's based on an `Incident`, how many activities will be shown.

I have come up with the following code to dynamically fill the GUI:

```
   List<Activity> activities = new List<Activity>();
            activities.Add(new Activity(1, 2, "Mail client", 5));
            activities.Add(new Activity(2, 2, "Fix problem", 5));
            activities.Add(new Activity(3, 2, "Mail client for success", 10));
            activities.Add(new Activity(4, 2, "Mail client", 5));

            int n = activities.Count();
            Label[] labels = new Label[n];
            TextBox[] textboxes = new TextBox[n];
            CheckBox[] checkboxes = new CheckBox[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                labels[i] = new Label();
                labels[i].Text = activities.ElementAt(i).Description.ToString();

                textboxes[i] = new TextBox();
                textboxes[i].Text = activities.ElementAt(i).TimeSpent.ToString();

                checkboxes[i] = new CheckBox();
            }
```

My first question was, how do we add these components to a GUI? Would I have another separate `for`-loop with a layout (or in my case, a `group box`) to store the items?

Secondly, how is it possible for me to link the checkbox with the activity. This because at a later stage, I would have to sum up the times of activities that have their checkbox checked. But would they be currently linked to an activity?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:
1. In your `Activities` class have static `StartX` and `StartY` to keep controls coordinates and write `DrawToForm` method like below:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public class Activity
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int IncidentID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int TimeSpent { get; set; }

        public static int StartX { get; set; } = 10;
        public static int StartY { get; set; } = 10;
        public Activity(int iD, int incidentID, string description, int timeSpent)
        {
            this.ID = iD;
            this.IncidentID = incidentID;
            this.Description = description;
            this.TimeSpent = timeSpent;
        }
        public void DrawToForm(Form f)
        {

            var label = new Label();
            var textBox = new TextBox();
            var checkBox = new CheckBox();
            label.Text = Description.ToString();
            textBox.Text = TimeSpent.ToString();
            label.Left = StartX;
            label.Top = StartY;
            StartX += 100;// Move position to right
            textBox.Left = StartX;
            textBox.Top = StartY;
            StartX += 150;// Move position to right
            checkBox.Left = StartX;
            checkBox.Top = StartY;
            StartX = 10;// Reset to start
            StartY += 50;// Move position to down
            f.Controls.Add(label);
            f.Controls.Add(textBox);
            f.Controls.Add(checkBox);
        }
    }
}
```

2. Now in `Form`'s constructor or anyway you need you can do this:

   ```
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       List<Activity> activities = new List<Activity>();
       activities.Add(new Activity(1, 2, "Mail client", 5));
       activities.Add(new Activity(2, 2, "Fix problem", 5));
       activities.Add(new Activity(3, 2, "Mail client for success", 10));
       activities.Add(new Activity(4, 2, "Mail client", 5));
       foreach(Activity a in activities)
       {
           a.DrawToForm(this);
       }
   }
   ```

   I have not write part of the Labels for Header part as it's not dynamical.

Comment: Thanks you very much! I was wondering for the `CheckBox`-problem, would it be a better idea to already add a `CheckBox` as a member in the `Activity´-class?

Comment: @KahnKah if you will save that checkbox value to Database or FileSystem and anywhere and then load it from there using `Activity` class,then of course you will need to have a property or a field for that checkbox .

Comment: Thank you very much @S.Petrosov